# Clearing wpf datagrid cells by user at runtime

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a datagrid that is supposed to be an 'input table' for the end user to work with. (User provides data, clicks a button and program processes the data)

It is bound to an ObservableCollection (User class contains simple stuff such as email, name, login etc)

Everything works fine binding wise... but, I want to allow the users to correct their input, i.e. select a row and delete it from the grid, or clear contents of several cells etc - not all fields are mandatory.

However, when Del key is pressed, nothing happens. I tried handling the previewKeyDown event etc, but I got to the problem described below:

[How I can Delete Selected Row in datagrid wpf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26506901/how-i-can-delete-selected-row-in-datagrid-wpf)

Does this mean I cannot delete items when I am using binding? I have no idea how could I reliably modify the underlying collection - how can I know if I should remove the value of Name, Login, Email - and of which user in my collection?

I thought that two way binding would take care of this...

My code:

```
ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=ThisUc,
            Path=UsersToCreate,
            Mode=TwoWay,
            UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"


private ObservableCollection<User> _usersToCreate;
        public ObservableCollection<User> UsersToCreate
        {
            get { return _usersToCreate ?? (_usersToCreate = new ObservableCollection<User>()); }
            set
            {
                _usersToCreate = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("UsersToCreate");
                ProgressBarMax = UsersToCreate.Count;
            }
        }
```

Cheers

Comment: bind to the selecteditem in your viewmodel. once the delete key is pressed, remove that item from the observablecollection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future reference, this is my full solution:

```
private void UserDataGrid_OnPreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        var grid = sender as System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid;
        if (e.Key == Key.Delete)
        {
            //treat each cell individually
            foreach (var item in grid.SelectedCells)
            {
                User user = item.Item as User;
                if (user == null)
                    continue;
                //clear the property of the selected cell
                foreach (var property in typeof(User).GetProperties())
                {
                    if (property.Name == item.Column.Header.ToString())
                    {
                        property.SetValue(user, null, null);
                    }
                }
                //recreated the user object
                User newUser = new User
                {
                    Login = user.Login,
                    Address = user.Address,
                    Email = user.Email,
                    Name = user.Name,
                    Description = user.Description
                };
                //remove the old one and place the new one to update collection visually (otherwise DataGrid updates when only double-clicked)
                var index = UsersToCreate.IndexOf(user);
                UsersToCreate.Remove(user);
                UsersToCreate.Insert(index, newUser);
            }
            //now check if any rows are completely empty - if so, then remove from DGV
            List<int> indexesToRemove = new List<int>();
            foreach (var user in UsersToCreate)
            {
                bool hasValue = false;
                foreach (var property in typeof(User).GetProperties())
                {
                    if (property.GetValue(user, null) != null)
                    {
                        hasValue = true;
                    }
                }
                if (!hasValue)
                {
                    indexesToRemove.Add(UsersToCreate.IndexOf(user));
                }
            }
            //go upside down to avoid index out of range (first remove last rows indexes)
            for (int i = indexesToRemove.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                var index = indexesToRemove[i];
                UsersToCreate.RemoveAt(index);
            }
        }
    }
```

Although it's large, I think it's all pretty neat, because it allows to select several cells in several rows and clear them without reordering the datagrid etc. But also, it allows to remove the whole rows if all properties are null for the user.

Sadly, I need to readd the user, as when I simply update the properties, datagrid does not update visually - the collection is updated, but you need to dbl-click on the specific property cell to see that it's been wiped.

Thanks for help everybody

Comment: Glad you made it :) If this is what worked for you, mark it as the answer, so others can find it easily

Answer (score 1):

> Does this mean I cannot delete items when I am using binding?

Nope. It just means that if you're setting your items through `ItemsSource`, the `DataGrid` has no control over that collection (it could be any type of collection!) and relies on you to handle it.

> I have no idea how could I reliably modify the underlying collection - how can I know if I should remove the value of Name, Login, Email - and of which user in my collection?

If you know the row, you know the user. The `User` object is the `DataContext` of the `DataGridRow` and its cells. You just have to remove that `User` from the `UsersToCreate` collection, and the `DataGrid` will update accordingly.

You could do this binding the `SelectedItem` property of the `DataGrid`, which will return the `User` object of the selected row.

As for clearing a given cell, it isn't that easy... Cells usually just represent properties of the data item of the row, the only way to clear its value is resetting that property to its default value. In this case, identifying the property is not simple.

The best way to clear a cell is using a `DataGridTemplateColumn` with some custom `TextBox` inside its template, that handles the `PreviewKeyUp` event and does a `TextBox.Clear()` when it detects the *Del* key is pressed and released.

Comment: Thanks - I will post my complete solution here :)

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can:

```
<DataGrid>
    <DataGrid.InputBindings>
        <KeyBinding Key="D" Command="{Binding DeleteCommand}" />
        <KeyBinding Key="Delete" Command="{Binding DeleteCommand}" />
    </DataGrid.InputBindings>
</DataGrid>
```

EDIT:
You can pass the selected item as parameter or do exactly as moncada suggests. For this to work I think the user have to select a row from the datagrid and not a cell, but not sure about that right now.